# May I move my parent site to here?

Tags: support, policy, moderators

This is now the SE site with the highest reputation for me. I would like to know if I am welcome here before I do?

I have learned much and will do my very best not to create work and contribute good questions.

Comment: Are you referring to the parent user of your chat account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may change your chat's parent site to here. However, *considering that you're currently suspended on the current parent site, **changing it doesn't lift your chat suspension.***

Reference: [Can you still chat if you change your parent site from where you are suspended to other site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270762/241919)